# ¿Cómo obtener la respuesta de nodejs/express desde Angular para mostrarla por consola?

Tags: nodejs, angular, express

Estoy intentando que `nodejs/express` al recibir los datos compruebe si falta algun dato, por el momento estoy ckecheando el `id_user`. Si hay algun error, hago un `return res.status(400)` con un mensage informando el error.
Ahora, como puedo obtener esa respuesta o mensaje de `nodejs/express` desde `Angular` para mostrarlo por consola para saber cual fue el error?.

aca en node.js `orders.controller.ts`

```js
export const createOrder = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response> => {

  // checkeando el id_user
  if (req.params.id_user === null) {
      return res.status(400).send({
      message: "FALTA CONTENIDO EN EL CUERPO, falta el id_user"
    })
  }
  //recibo los datos (de un form, insomnia rest, etc..)
  const { id_user, adress, phone_number, total_price, provincia, localidad, order_date } = (req.body);
  console.log(id_user, adress, phone_number, total_price, provincia, localidad, order_date)
  // el id_order en la db es autonumerico no hace falta
  let idUser = parseInt(id_user);
  let totalPrice = parseInt(total_price);

  const response: QueryResult = await pool.query('INSERT INTO orders (id_user, adress, phone_number, total_price, provincia, localidad, order_date) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7)', [idUser, adress, phone_number, totalPrice, provincia, localidad, order_date]);
  return res.json({
    message: 'La orden ah sido creado exitosamente!',
    body: {
      orders: {
        adress
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Aca `Angular`donde envío a `nodejs/express` la orden creada

```js
createOrder() {
    this.order.id_user = null;
    this.order.order_date = this.currentDate;
    this.order.total_price = this.total;
    this.orderService.createOrder(this.order).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log('La orden fue creada exitosamente');
        this.createOrderDetail(); //??
      },
      err => console.log('No se pudo crear la orden ' + err)
    );
  }
```

Aca el servicio `order.service.ts`

```js
createOrder(order: Order){
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:4000/orders/create', order);
  }
```

Comment: Ya estas capturando el error con err => console.log('No se pudo crear la orden ' + err) si quieres mostrar el mensaje directamente en ves de err pondrias err.message que es el mensaje de la respuesta de tu backend

Comment: Debes verificar el estado de la respuesta en Angular. El objeto de error es para determinar si hubo un error en la llamada a tu servicio, en cambio si el servicio responde con un status 400 eso no es un error en la llamada. Para determinar el estado de la respuesta verifica el valor de `res.status`. Saludos

Answer (score -2):

En node, req.params.id_user debe estar llegando como undefined, por eso. undefined es distinto de null para ===. Prueba esto en js:

```
if (undefined === null){ 
        console.log('son iguales');
}else{ 
        console.log('son distintos'); 
}
```

Comment: Por favor, esto no responde la pregunta. Cuando tengas la [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) suficiente podrás dejar [comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) en cualquier publicación. Te sugiero que elimines esta respuesta, ya que no es una respuesta válida. Puedes leer [answer]. Saludos